# How to trigger FancyBox close from within its iframe content which is on different domain?

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, cross-domain

I have a webpart in a certain website that must load (once opened) a login page (which is on a different domain then the website) inside fancybox iframe, then when signing in for the first time it should show inside that iframe (fancybox) a message to grant access with YES/NO options. So i want that once i click on any of the buttons of YES/NO to close the fancybox iframe. I tried to access the parent page but of course it didn't allow me because of domain name issues. All i want is to be able to close the fancybox popup (iframe). Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it and hope that the solution will help you if you had a similar situation. I solved it using "postMessage", here's the solution:

1- in my webpart:
I put the following javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        if (event.data == 'close') {                
            $.fancybox.close();
        }
    }, false);
```

2- in my website:

```
parent.postMessage("close", "*");
```

I hope it clarify things. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the code within the iFrame and its parent you could use `window.postMessage(...)`

I believe IE8+ and any other current browser will support this.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage